# Why Linq Expression Tree polymorphism work correctly?

Tags: .net, expression-trees

I have code like this:

```
if(expression.GetType() == typeof(BinaryExpression))
{
 //DO something
}
```

expression is a MethodBinaryExpression (doing a `Console.WriteLines(expression.GetType().ToString()` says so). However, the code never gets into the if-block. `MethodBinaryExpression` is a child class of `SimpleBinaryExpression` which is a child class of `BinaryExpression`. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the test to this:

```
if(expression is BinaryExpression) 
{ 
 //DO something 
}
```

Even if MethodBinaryExpression inherits from BinaryExpression, they are still different types. You can try out a few examples to see how Type objects compare:

```
// Prints "False"
Console.WriteLine(typeof(MethodBinaryExpression) == typeof(BinaryExpression)); 

// Prints "True"
Console.WriteLine(typeof(BinaryExpression) == typeof(BinaryExpression));
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't know why I keep thinking C#'s == will traverse the whole inheritance tree. That worked perfectly.